# react-native-app-badge not working until the device receives the first notification

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, badge

I'm developing an app using react native.
I implemented the badge feature using react-native-app-badge on android, but the setCount doesn't work until the device receives the first notification. does anyone know any information about this?

I tried another library for badges, but it didn't work

--

If the push notification does not exist in the Notification Center, the badge will not be represented.